# "chain/transitive" join optimal way

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following looks easy problem, but I can't find an optimal way to create the query.

I have a table where there is pairs and it all has a party_id.

| name | name_pair | party_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | A1 | 1 |
| A | A2 | 2 |
| A2 | C1 | 3 |
| B2 | D1 | 4 |
| B2 | E1 | 5 |

Since [A,A1], [A,A2], [A2,C1] its means that **[A,A1,A2,C1]** should be together and the common party_id should the min of all these party_id so **1**
A-> A,A1,A2->C1 -> A,A1,A2,C1

The other party is [B2,D1,E1] -> **4**

What i want to see in result:

| name | name_pair | party_id | result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | A1 | 1 | 1 |
| A | A2 | 2 | 1 |
| A2 | C1 | 3 | 1 |
| B2 | D1 | 4 | 4 |
| B2 | E1 | 5 | 4 |

First i tried to cross join, but it only sloves until the party size  is 2...

Speed is important because this table has millions of rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand your case, you need a recursive query since C1 is the pair of A2 which is a pair of A. Here is a solution which will take some time because it requires to scan the full table in the first part of the recursive query even if an index on column `name` exists and should be used by the query planner in the second part :

```
WITH RECURSIVE list (name, name_pair, party_id, result, checks) AS (
  SELECT *
       , min(party_id) OVER (PARTITION BY name)
       , array[name]
    FROM mytable AS name
  UNION ALL
  SELECT t.*
       , least(l.result, min(t.party_id) OVER (PARTITION BY t.name))
       , l.checks || t.name
    FROM list AS l
   INNER JOIN mytable AS t
      ON t.name = l.name_pair
   WHERE NOT l.checks @> array[t.name] -- this condition avoids infinite loops
)
SELECT name
     , name_pair
     , party_id
     , min(result) AS result
  FROM list
 GROUP BY name, name_pair, party_id
```

see the test result in [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/1SK4_oCa)